# How to solve this differential equation using scipy odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve the following differential equation using scipy odeint without much success:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.integrate import odeint

Imag = 16000.
w = 2*np.pi*60
tau = .05
theta = 1.52
phi = theta - np.radians(90)
t = np.linspace(0,.1,10000)
def Ip(t):
    return np.sqrt(2)*Imag*(np.sin(w*t+phi-theta)-np.exp(-t/tau)*np.sin(phi-theta))

B = lambda Ip: Ip/(53.05+0.55*abs(Ip))
def L(B):
    return derivative(B,Ip(t))*377.2

def dI(t):
    return derivative(Ip,t)

def f(y,t):
    Rb = 8.
    N = 240.
    Is = y[0]
    f0 = (1/(L(B)+0.002))*((dI(t)*L(B)/N)-Rb*y[0])
    return [f0]

yinit = [0]
sol = odeint(f,yinit,t)
print sol[:,0]
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

What should I do to run the script without errors?

Answer (score 0):

what about using `ode` instead of `odeint`

there is a question quite similiar to yours:
[How to make odeint successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9466046/1942936)

Comment: How @Luyi does it help in solving my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with this function:

```
def L(B):
    return derivative(B,Ip(t))*377.2
```

Note that `t` refers to the global variable defined earlier, which is a numpy array.  I think you need to rethink how you define your functions and their arguments--should `t` also be an argument to `L`?  As it is, `f` returns a list containing an array, even when its first argument contains a single element:

```
In [10]: f([1], 0)
Out[10]: 
[array([ -2.28644086e+10,  -2.28638809e+10,  -2.28633064e+10, ...,
        -1.80290012e+09,  -1.80271510e+09,  -1.80258446e+09])]
```

That will cause `odeint` to break.

Comment: Yes I can see that. L is a function of 'dB/dI' whereas f is a function of 'dIs/dt'. I just can't figure out how to re-define the functions.